# Indentify soundtrack in Banged Up Abroad S08E06

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

In the episode Fast, [Mexico/Mexican Prison Escape](https://youtu.be/IuAD0XSo3BA?t=44m15s) of Banged up Abroad (S08E06) a track is played in the background at 44:15. Hope u will help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the [answer to another question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/indentify-soundtrack-in-banged-up-abroad-s08e09), it is revealed that the music cue-to-cue etc for this series is available on this [Fox website](http://ficcontentsales.com/programmes/Documents.aspx?id=1613). The series numbers seem to vary from country to country, which is why the Fox website has this as S09. The document you want is "Banged Up Abroad 9 Mexican Prison Escape MCS.xlsx".  From here it gets confusing. If you assume that the times in the document match the times of the vid on youtube, this should be some incidental music called "To Interrogation" (less percussion),  credited to [Anne Nitkin](http://www.annenikitin.com/), a noted film/TV music composer.  However, it looks more likely that this is some other music in the final minute or so of the episode, which might make it either "Sweet Freedom v2", credited to [Tom Howe](http://www.tomhowe.co.uk/), or "Bang 9" credited to [Ty Unwin](https://www.discogs.com/artist/152400-Ty-Unwin).    Given that the guys are getting away to freedom at this point, I would go for it being "Sweet Freedom".

Comment: [National Geographic](http://www.natgeotv.com/uk/shows/natgeo/banged-up-abroad#episodes-t9) also counts it as **S09E01**.